# how to loadmore laravel using jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel, pagination

hai i have a many data from **users** table, i want to make **load more** when button **load more** is clicked, ordered data is show,

this is my frontend

[image]

when button **strong text** load more is clicked, will show the next data,, BUT when i clicked **load more** button , 
the data is the same as the data above, order 1 - 10 again, not the next data in the database, like this

[image]

the data is same like above data,,

this is my JS

```
     getDataCall('/leaderboard/all').then(function (result) {
                setCookie('user_token', result.token, 14);

                data = result.data;
                list = $('#all-leaderboard');


                // $('#btn-loadMore').remove();
                // $('#all-leaderboard').append(data);

                 $('#btn-loadMore').click(function(){
                     $('#btn-loadMore').html('loading');

                     $.each(result.data, function (i, value) {
                         list.append(
                            '<h3>'+value.get_user.name+'</h3>'

                         );
                     });
                 });
```

this is my controller with PHP Laravel

```
  $logPoint = LogPoint::with(['getUser' => function($q){
        $q->select('id', 'name');
    }])

        ->select('user_id','point', 'created_at')
        ->orderBy('point', 'DESC')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')
        ->limit(10)
        ->get();
```

is using limit for limit data , when i using `paginate()` the data does not appear, how to solved this ?

thanks !

Comment: when you do `limit(10)`, it will always fetch first 10. Use it along with [`offset()`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset), and send the offset value in your ajax request

Comment: how to do this ? give me example

Comment: Offset will be the number of records/rows to skip when fetching records from your database. You can count the number of already loaded users through js (or you can pass the offset value from the server itself, whichever method to use is upto you), this will be your offset. Now send this offset value as a parameter when making the request, for example as a parameter `offset`. Then in your controller add this function call to the model `->offset($request->offset)`.

Comment: example code plis,, i dont understand

Comment: Instead of using limit/offset, you can use the built-in pagination https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination#paginating-eloquent-results , simply call `->paginate(10)` and cut out the `->get()`.  Then you have to make sure to send a `?page=2` to your backend to fetch the correct page.